# Can I add constraints with pandas to_sql method?

Tags: python, sql, pandas, sqlalchemy

I have a pandas dataframe I want to save in a DB table by using `pandas.DataFrame.to_sql` method. Is it possible to fine-tune the table's schema with this method? Specifically, I'd like to make all columns non-nullable and define a primary key. I see that the `dtype` parameter lets you provide specific types from sqlalchemy but I'm not familiar with sqlalchemy and taking a brief look at some of sqlalchemy types' constructors I see nothing like `nullable` parameter.

Comment: is your goal to create a table then make insertions to it ?

Comment: Matina G, pandas' to_sql automatically creates the table for you if it doesn't exist. I could create it first but that seems like a lot of low-level work pandas already takes care of

Comment: That is why I asked the question: From the documentaton of pandas.to_sql I do not see how to declare keys, restrictions etc. But perhaps we could guide you through your problem in sql alchemy - it is not as complicated as it might seem

Comment: I'm achieving this with `alter table` in raw SQL now but this is SQL dialect specific and requires that I know all the data types in the resulting table. If there is a way to do this by using pandas alone that's going to be ideal but if not I'd appreciate any help on how to do this with sqlalchemy.